# How do I perform XOR encryption in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to perform XOR encryption in PHP and I am having a lot of difficulty finding what script produces the correct output. I first used http://snipplr.com/view/8421/xor-encryptdecrypt/ script, and I altered it so it **DOES NOT** return the encrypted text as base64 encoded. I also removed it from a class. Here's my code:

```php
$key = "My key";

function get_rnd_iv($iv_len)
{
    $iv = '';
    while ($iv_len-- > 0)
    {
        $iv .= chr(mt_rand() & 0xff);
    }
    return $iv;
}

function encrypt($plain_text, $iv_len = 16)
{
    $plain_text .= "\x13";
    $n = strlen($plain_text);
    if ($n % 16)
    {
        $plain_text .= str_repeat("\0", 16 - ($n % 16));
        $i = 0;
        $enc_text = get_rnd_iv($iv_len);
        $iv = substr($key ^ $enc_text, 0, 512);
        while ($i < $n)
        {
            $block = substr($plain_text, $i, 16) ^ pack('H*', sha1($iv));
            $enc_text .= $block;
            $iv = substr($block . $iv, 0, 512) ^ $key;
            $i += 16;
        }
        //return base64_encode($enc_text);
        return $enc_text;
    } else {}
}

function decrypt($enc_text, $iv_len = 16)
{
    //$enc_text = base64_decode($enc_text);
    $n = strlen($enc_text);
    $i = $iv_len;
    $plain_text = '';
    $iv = substr($key ^ substr($enc_text, 0, $iv_len), 0, 512);
    while ($i < $n)
    {
        $block = substr($enc_text, $i, 16);
        $plain_text .= $block ^ pack('H*', sha1($iv));
        $iv = substr($block . $iv, 0, 512) ^ $key;
        $i += 16;
    }
    return stripslashes(preg_replace('/\\x13\\x00*$/', '', $plain_text));
}

$enc = encrypt('text');
echo 'Encrypted: '.$enc.'<br />';
echo 'Decrypted: '.decrypt($enc);
```

Now, when I run this, I get:

```php
Encrypted: ¥Õlµê®M²:Ýë??ÞÂ=ç²¸ È,ñ ™ÑÂÔ ¹
Decrypted: text
```

**EDIT:**

Each time I run, I get a different output?!

However, the following sites produce results completely different from that snippet:
 http://www.abcel-online.com/tools.php?id=decrypt
 http://th.atguy.com/mycode/xor_js_encryption/

I also tried the code from this site: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5555

Please tell me which one is correct, and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The undefined `$key` variable _within_ the `encrypt()` function - what is it supposed to be?  `$plain_text`?

Comment: $key was defined at the top `$key = "My key";`

Comment: You defined `$key` outside the scope of the `encrypt()` function, so the function has no visibility to it.

Comment: I've made $key global, put `global $key;` in each function, and even set $key each time in each function. It still doesn't work. Also, **each time I run, it produces a different output**

Comment: your entire problem might be hinging on the fact the that lone `$key` value you declared at the top of your example does not exist within the scope of any of your functions.  However, you provided only several untrusted external websites to test and compare against, which makes it impossible to help you further.  Can you give any expected results as examples instead?

Comment: An expected result is: **Encrypted:
Decrypted: text** ... Edit: it seems this site removes the text. It should produce a 4 letter unreadable text like the example I posted

Answer (score 1):

You are using a random IV, which is explictly used to generate different cipher text for each run of the function. This is to make sure you don't leak information about the plain text. E.g. otherwise encrypting the word "yes" twice would result in the same cipher text. Note that you may still have a leak regarding the *size* of the cipher text, which is related to the size of the plain text.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer, JRunner (looking at some old answers of mine)